# Enable Codec on FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm tryiing to use g711 alaw with ffmpeg. The call
    avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_PCM_ALAW);
returns null. 
I'm passing --enable-encoder=pcm_alaw as parameter to ./configure.
What is wrong?

Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ffmpeg executable compiled, you use "ffmpeg -formats" command line to see what codecs are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Did you called av_register_all() before find encoder?